# How to sort descending from multidimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an json object. I just want to change each channel array channel_sales_value sort descending that's it nothing else. In my array, each channel key will be same position. I tried to make it array.sort() method, array.reverse(), array.map() but I can't solve it. How can I solve it?

```js
var array = {
      amazon: {
         channel_session: 1,
         channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-blue-dark',
         channel_sales_name: 'Amazon Sales',
         channel_name: 'amazon',
         channel_sales_value: '0.00'
      }
     ebay: {
        channel_session: 1,
        channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-cherry',
        channel_sales_name: 'eBay Sales',
        channel_name: 'ebay',
        channel_sales_value: '91,162.99'
     }
    manual_order: {
        channel_session: 0,
        channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-ash-dark',
        channel_sales_name: 'ePOS Sales',
        channel_name: 'manual-order',
        channel_sales_value: '2,874.31'
     }
    onbuy: { 
        channel_session: 1,
        channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-orange-dark',
        channel_sales_name: 'OnBuy Sales',
        channel_name: 'onbuy',
        channel_sales_value: '226.44'
    }
    shopify: {
      channel_session: 1,
      channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-light-green-orange',
      channel_sales_name: 'Shopify Sales',
      channel_name: 'shopify',
      channel_sales_value: '279.95'
   }
    woocommerce: {
      channel_session: 1,
      channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-green-dark',
      channel_sales_name: 'WooCommerce Sales',
      channel_name: 'website',
      channel_sales_value: '6,458.11'
    }
}
```

I want to make it looks like this array. Array has given below.

```js
var array = {
     ebay: {
          channel_session: 1,
          channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-cherry',
          channel_sales_name: 'eBay Sales',
          channel_name: 'ebay',
          channel_sales_value: '91,162.99'
      }
      woocommerce: {
         channel_session: 1,
         channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-green-dark',
         channel_sales_name: 'WooCommerce Sales',
         channel_name: 'website',
         channel_sales_value: '6,458.11'
     }
     manual_order: {
          channel_session: 0,
          channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-ash-dark',
          channel_sales_name: 'ePOS Sales',
          channel_name: 'manual-order',
          channel_sales_value: '2,874.31'
    }
    shopify: {
         channel_session: 1,
         channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-light-green-orange',
         channel_sales_name: 'Shopify Sales',
         channel_name: 'shopify',
         channel_sales_value: '279.95'
    }
    onbuy: {
         channel_session: 1,
         channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-orange-dark',
         channel_sales_name: 'OnBuy Sales',
         channel_name: 'onbuy',
         channel_sales_value: '226.44'
    }
    amazon: {
         channel_session: 1,
         channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-blue-dark',
         channel_sales_name: 'Amazon Sales',
         channel_name: 'amazon',
         channel_sales_value: '0.00'
    }
}
```

Comment: your array is an object so the key order is not guaranteed

Comment: @cmgchess - It is but the rules are complex and it depends on how the object is created, so making use of that guarantee is a very bad idea. :-)

Comment: There no JSON and there's no array.  You'll find finding a solution much easier if you know what these things are (and what they are not).

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not an array, it's an object.

So, you need to take the values and make a list.

Then you can sort it like this:

```js
    var array = {
          amazon: {
             channel_session: 1,
             channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-blue-dark',
             channel_sales_name: 'Amazon Sales',
             channel_name: 'amazon',
             channel_sales_value: '0.00'
          },
         ebay: {
            channel_session: 1,
            channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-cherry',
            channel_sales_name: 'eBay Sales',
            channel_name: 'ebay',
            channel_sales_value: '91,162.99'
         },
        manual_order: {
            channel_session: 0,
            channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-ash-dark',
            channel_sales_name: 'ePOS Sales',
            channel_name: 'manual-order',
            channel_sales_value: '2,874.31'
         },
        onbuy: { 
            channel_session: 1,
            channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-orange-dark',
            channel_sales_name: 'OnBuy Sales',
            channel_name: 'onbuy',
            channel_sales_value: '226.44'
        },
        shopify: {
          channel_session: 1,
          channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-light-green-orange',
          channel_sales_name: 'Shopify Sales',
          channel_name: 'shopify',
          channel_sales_value: '279.95'
       },
        woocommerce: {
          channel_session: 1,
          channel_card_bg_class: 'l-bg-green-dark',
          channel_sales_name: 'WooCommerce Sales',
          channel_name: 'website',
          channel_sales_value: '6,458.11'
        }
    }

    let toList = Object.values(array)
    console.table(toList)

let sorted = toList.sort(function(a, b) { 
    let aParsed = parseFloat(a.channel_sales_value.replace(/,/g, ''))
    let bParsed = parseFloat(b.channel_sales_value.replace(/,/g, ''))

    return  bParsed - aParsed ;
})

console.table(sorted)
```

And now build again your object.